# Input type=”text” box reloads page when lowercase “t” is input

Tags: html

This is the most bizarre problem I’ve ever seen.  I have three text input boxes on a page, one for email address and two for first name and last name.  I can input any letter or character in the fields EXCEPT lowercase “t” which causes the page to reload.  The css classes have nothing to do with it because when I remove the classes the problem is still there.

Here’s the code for the email input field:

```
  <div class="center_text_grid mktg_text">
    <input type="text" class="joinpage_input" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" maxlength="50" style="width:80%;" required></div>
```

This happens before the form is submitted -- just when the user enters a lowercase "t" -- no other letter or character causes this problem.

So my question is:  why would entering a lowercase t into a name or email address cause the page to reload?  Is there any workaround?

Comment: That's such a cool problem Can you make a minimal reproduction of the bug?
Surely if you strip more and more stuff from your page the problem will disappear eventually.

Comment: Simply running your code above does not cause the problem. Can you please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: First suspect is some javascript rogue

Comment: It looks like I've solved this problem.  Lowercase t is ascii 116.  I have javascript code that causes special actions when e.keyCode == 116 because that also corresponds to F5.  So that caused it.  I'll see about removing or altering that javascript.

Comment: So @Kai Qing, you were right -- a javascript rogue.

Comment: Followup -- I removed the javascript code that handled F5 with keycode 116, and now I can enter lowercase t in the boxes and no page reload.  Problem solved.  My only question is why F5 and lowercase t share the same keycode?

Comment: That is a good question... I wonder how often a keycode thing I set picked up some other key. Well ok then. Glad it worked